# Alamofire compiled with older version of Swift language (2.0) than previous files (3.0) for architecture x86_64

Tags: swift, alamofire

When I move my program to the XCode8, I got this error: Alamofire compiled with older version of Swift language (2.0) than previous files (3.0) for architecture x86_64.
I have update Alamofire to version 4.0, and set the Use Legacy Swift Language Version to NO.
What's the matter?

Comment: update you pod, and again pod install with latest version

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but only update the pod is not enough, the answer of KAR is useful.@iDeveloper

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update your cocoa pods and clear your derive data folder and try to run again.

In xcode 8 derived data folder changed,

Go to File -> Workspace setting -> then see this image,

[image]

Click on -> on path and clear that derived data folder.

Comment: than up vote answer so it helps someone other. and accept the answer. @Tony_Liu

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall pods and install it again. Use below commands to install the pods in app

1) pod repo update (make sure you are at root folder)

2) sudo gem install cocoapods --pre (make sure you are at root folder)

3) move to your application folder and run following command:

pod init

4) pod install

Remove derived data folder, clean the app and run it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Carthage, try run:

```
carthage update --no-use-binaries
```

Answer (score -1):

For me the issue was with Carthage because i have set manualy the version of Alamofire the old version.

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 3.0
```

To solve the issue, Go in Cartfile and just delete the version like this :

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire"
```

Go in the console and tap :

> carthage update

[image]

Now your framework is generated with the good version