# Function not working after Swift 3 conversion, cannot figure out why

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if saveButton === sender {


        var patientNumber = loadPatients()

        let id = String(Int((patientNumber?.count)!) + 1)
        let name = patientNameTextField.text ?? ""
        let location = patientLocationTextField.text ?? ""
        let status = "Ok"
        let bluetoothAddress = peripheralKeyArray[pickedAddressRow]

        // Set the meal to be passed to MealTableViewController after the unwind segue.
        patient = Patient(id: id, name: name, location: location, status: status, bluetoothAddress: bluetoothAddress)

        //Kill Timer before view closed
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

The problem's are

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
```

and

```
if saveButton === sender {
```

> Cannot override instance method parameter of type 'Any?' with non-optional type 'Any'
>
> Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UIBarButtonItem!' and 'Any'

I do not understand these errors even after searching about them. Would really appreciate it if someone could simplify an explanation for me. :) Thank you!

Comment: clear derived data file and run it again. for locatin of derived data file you can refer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657436/alamofire-compiled-with-older-version-of-swift-language-2-0-than-previous-file/39657541#39657541. @vevek

Comment: `sender` is an optional. `Any?` and `Any` are not the same thing. Unwrap `sender`.

Comment: @DanielStorm You can't compare two `Any` using `===` either.

Comment: @KAR I did that, unfortunately it did not solve the error..

Comment: @DanielStorm I don't understand that. I experimented with unwrapping the sender, however it didn't work. Currently I changed the code to     

func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: UIButton) {
        if saveButton === sender {

however I get this error now. /Users/vevek/AscentHome/AscentHome/PatientViewController.swift:31:57: Cannot override instance method parameter of type 'Any?' with non-optional type 'Any'

Comment: @Hamish Thank you so much! That solved the problem. :)