# Swift private Framework with backward xcode version compatibility

Tags: swift, xcode, backwards-compatibility, swift-framework, version-compatibility

This is my first framework using Swift language and it's private framework. It's worked as expected until new Xcode 9.3 release. After upgrading newer `Xcode` got an issue like this `Module compiled with Swift 4.0.3 cannot be imported in Swift 4.1`.

After that only I realized framework doesn't support auto version (Xcode/Swift) upgrade, Did some search found there is a `Universal or Fat Binary Framework` single build instead of separate build for real device and simulator which I missed in previously.

```
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

# Make sure the output directory exists

mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Next, work out if we're in SIM or DEVICE

xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build

xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build

# Step 2. Copy the framework structure (from iphoneos build) to the universal folder

cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

# Step 3. Copy Swift modules from iphonesimulator build (if it exists) to the copied framework directory

BUILD_PRODUCTS="${SYMROOT}/../../../../Products"

cp -R "${BUILD_PRODUCTS}/Debug-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule/." "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule"

# Step 4. Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory

lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_PRODUCTS}/Debug-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"

# Step 5. Convenience step to copy the framework to the project's directory

cp -R "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${PROJECT_DIR}"

# Step 6. Convenience step to open the project's directory in Finder
open "${PROJECT_DIR}"
fi
```

At `Edit Scheme` -> `Archive` -> `Post-Action` -> `Run Script`

This time I am used `Swift Compiler - Language` -> `Swift 3.3`

And I got expected output this time too in `Xcode 9.3` with `Swift 4.1`

When I try to run the project with this framework at `Xcode 9.2` it's show error like this
`Module compiled with Swift 4.1 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2.3:`

Try to resolve with backward compatibility and I didn't find. How can I run this framework in `Xcode 9.2`

Framework support: `Swift` and `Objective C`, Min OS `iOS 8.0`

## **Update**

Also got something like this error
`compiled with newer version of Swift language (unknown ABI version 0x06) than previous files (4.0) file 'MAC location' for architecture armv7`
And tried [this to my project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39657541)